# Download file using HtmlUnit

Tags: download, htmlunit

I am trying to download xls file for a website. When I click the link to download the file, I get a javascript confirm box. I handle it like below

```
    ConfirmHandler okHandler = new ConfirmHandler(){
            public boolean handleConfirm(Page page, String message) {
                return true;
            }
        };
    webClient.setConfirmHandler(okHandler);
```

There is a link to download file.

```
<a href="./my_file.php?mode=xls&amp;w=d2hlcmUgc2VsbElkPSd3b3JsZGNvbScgYW5kIHN0YXR1cz0nV0FJVERFTEknIGFuZCBkYXRlIDw9IC0xMzQ4MTUzMjAwICBhbmQgZGF0ZSA%2BPSAtMTM1MDgzMTU5OSA%3D" target="actionFrame" onclick="return confirm('Do you want do download XLS file?')"><u>Download</u></a>
```

I click the link using

```
HTMLPage x = webClient.getPage("http://working.com/download");
HtmlAnchor anchor = (HtmlAnchor) x.getFirstByXPath("//a[@target='actionFrame']");
anchor.click();
```

handeConfirm() method is excuted. But I have no idea how to save the file stream from server. I tried to see the stream with code below.

```
anchor.click().getWebResponse().getContentAsString();
```

But, the result is same as the page x. Anyone knows how to capture the stream from server?  Thank you.

Comment: `anchor.click()` will return a page. That should contian your XLS file

Comment: see my answer to a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/a/28471835/612123

Answer (score 10):

I found a way to get InputStream using WebWindowListener. Inside of webWindowContentChanged(WebWindowEvent event), I put code below.

```
InputStream xls = event.getWebWindow().getEnclosedPage().getWebResponse().getContentAsStream();
```

After I get xls, I could save the file into my hard disk.

Comment: I am downloading a csv file, can you pls explain what is event and when are you calling the click event on anchor. I dont have confirmation box for downloading file.

Comment: @Naveen This works exactly as described above, except that instead of `.getContentAsStream()` you'll be using `getContentAsString()` and then you can `String.split("\n")` to get individual lines, and then split the lines once again with `String.split(",")` to get the info on each individual line.

Answer (score 9):

I made it based on your post.. Note: you can change content-type condition for download only specific type of file. eg.( application/octect-stream, application/pdf, etc).

```
package net.s4bdigital.export.main;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ConfirmHandler;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.Page;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebResponse;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebWindowEvent;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebWindowListener;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.util.NameValuePair;

public class HtmlUnitDownloadFile {

    protected String baseUrl;
    protected static WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void openBrowser() {
        baseUrl = "http://localhost/teste.html";
        driver = new CustomHtmlUnitDriver();
        ((HtmlUnitDriver) driver).setJavascriptEnabled(true);

    }


    @Test
    public void downloadAFile() throws Exception {

        driver.get(baseUrl);
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("click to Downloadfile")).click();

    }

    public class CustomHtmlUnitDriver extends HtmlUnitDriver { 

          // This is the magic. Keep a reference to the client instance 
           protected WebClient modifyWebClient(WebClient client) { 


             ConfirmHandler okHandler = new ConfirmHandler(){
                    public boolean handleConfirm(Page page, String message) {
                        return true;
                    }
             };
             client.setConfirmHandler(okHandler);

             client.addWebWindowListener(new WebWindowListener() {

                public void webWindowOpened(WebWindowEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                public void webWindowContentChanged(WebWindowEvent event) {

                    WebResponse response = event.getWebWindow().getEnclosedPage().getWebResponse();
                    System.out.println(response.getLoadTime());
                    System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
                    System.out.println(response.getContentType());

                    List<NameValuePair> headers = response.getResponseHeaders();
                    for(NameValuePair header: headers){
                        System.out.println(header.getName() + " : " + header.getValue());
                    }

                    // Change or add conditions for content-types that you would to like 
                    // receive like a file.
                    if(response.getContentType().equals("text/plain")){
                        getFileResponse(response, "target/testDownload.war");
                    }



                }

                public void webWindowClosed(WebWindowEvent event) {



                }
            });          

             return client; 
           } 


    } 

    public static void getFileResponse(WebResponse response, String fileName){

        InputStream inputStream = null;

        // write the inputStream to a FileOutputStream
        OutputStream outputStream = null; 

        try {       

            inputStream = response.getContentAsStream();

            // write the inputStream to a FileOutputStream
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName));

            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }

            System.out.println("Done!");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (outputStream != null) {
                try {
                    // outputStream.flush();
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I m sorry but I dont get it, where or how exactly are you keeping the reference to `webclient` in `modifywebclient` method......thanks

Comment: https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/htmlunit/HtmlUnitDriver.html#modifyWebClient(com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient)

Anudeep Samaiya

Is a method of superclass..  we can override it adding a handle to confirm windows of download file.. But u need modify content type waited in your case.

Comment: I have faced one problem like it downloads the file but not the complete. Content of the file is half.

Comment: @viralpatel I never faced it , however I have a clue, did you already verified the "Content-Length" header in http response in our especific case ? is it correct ?

Comment: @EduardoFabricio can you guide me how I can verify the 'Content-Length' header. Actually, I'm trying to download file that has 101 row when I download the file manually or using chrome driver but when I try with the HTML unit it has only 70 row.

Comment: I've tried everything. quite incredible that this worked

Answer (score 3):

There's an easier way if you're not into wrapping HtmlUnit with Selenium. Simply provide HtmlUnit's WebClient with the extended WebWindowListener.

You could also use Apache commons.io for easy stream copying.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.addWebWindowListener(new WebWindowListener() {
    public void webWindowOpened(WebWindowEvent event) { }

    public void webWindowContentChanged(WebWindowEvent event) {
        // Change or add conditions for content-types that you would
        // to like receive like a file.
        if (response.getContentType().equals("text/plain")) {
            try {
                IOUtils.copy(response.getContentAsStream(), new FileOutputStream("downloaded_file"));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public void webWindowClosed(WebWindowEvent event) {}
});
```

Comment: how to get response  in webWindowContentChanged method?

Answer (score 2):

```
 final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
        webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(2000);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(2000);

        //get General page
        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://your");

        //get Frame
        final HtmlPage frame = ((HtmlPage) 
        page.getFrameByName("Frame").getEnclosedPage());

        webClient.setConfirmHandler(new ConfirmHandler() {
            public boolean handleConfirm(Page page, String message) {
                return true;
            }
        });

        //get element file
        final DomElement file = mainFrame.getElementByName("File");

        final InputStream xls =  file.click().getWebResponse().getContentAsStream();

        assertNotNull(xls);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Roy's answer, here's my solution to this problem:

```
public static void prepareForDownloadingFile(WebClient webClient, File output) {
    webClient.addWebWindowListener(new WebWindowListener() {

        public void webWindowOpened(WebWindowEvent event) {
        }

        public void webWindowContentChanged(WebWindowEvent event) {
            Page page = event.getNewPage();
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            InputStream is = null;
            if (page != null && page instanceof UnexpectedPage) {
                try {
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(output);
                    UnexpectedPage uPage = (UnexpectedPage) page;
                    is = uPage.getInputStream();
                    IOUtils.copy(is, fos);
                    webClient.removeWebWindowListener(this);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (fos != null)
                            fos.close();
                        if (is != null)
                            is.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        public void webWindowClosed(WebWindowEvent event) {
        }
    });
}
```

I felt there were enough differences to make it a new answer:
-Doesn't have a magic variable (`response`)
-Closes `InputStream` and `FileOutputStream`
-Looks for `UnexpectedPage` to determine we're not on a HTML page
-Downloads a file one time after requesting then removes itself
-Doesn't require knowing the `ContentType`

Calling this once before, for example, clicking a button that initiates a download, will download that file.

Answer (score -1):

> Figure out the download URL, and scrape it in List. from the download url we can get the entire file using this code.

```
    try{
        String path = "your destination path";
        List<HtmlElement> downloadfiles = (List<HtmlElement>) page.getByXPath("the tag you want to scrape");
        if (downloadfiles.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No items found !");
        } else {
            for (HtmlElement htmlItem : downloadfiles) {
                String DownloadURL = htmlItem.getHrefAttribute();

                Page invoicePdf = client.getPage(DownloadURL);
                if (invoicePdf.getWebResponse().getContentType().equals("application/pdf")) {
                    System.out.println("creatign PDF:");
                    IOUtils.copy(invoicePdf.getWebResponse().getContentAsStream(),
                            new FileOutputStream(path + "file name"));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```