# HtmlUnit download file

Tags: java, javascript, htmlunit

I am trying to download file via HTMLUnit. But every time when I use code like this:

```
InputStream stream  = anchor.click().getWebResponse().getContentAsStream();
```

i get website instead file.

Download link looks like this:

```
<a id="j_id272:exportToExcel" onclick="if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){jsfcljs(document.forms['j_id272'],'j_id272:exportToExcel,j_id272:exportToExcel','');}return false" href="#">
     <img id="j_id272:exportToExcelImage" alt="???exportToExcel???" src="/ECRM/gfx/icon_excel.gif">
</a>
```

Is there any way to download this?

Comment: why don't you use this link: http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/htmlunit/htmlunit/2.15/htmlunit-2.15-bin.zip?r=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F25136439%2Fhtmlunit-download-file&ts=1407234257&use_mirror=softlayer-ams

Comment: You missunderstand me. I don't have a problem with download htmlunit. I want to download file via htmlunit.

Comment: ah ok. well the problem is, that there is no direct download link. there is some javascript that does the magic.

Comment: Any idea how can I download that file?

Answer (score 0):

```
Page page = anchor.click();
BinaryPage bp = new BinaryPage(page.getWebResponse(),page.getEnclosingWindow());
InputStream input = bp.getInputStream();
```

What is inside your page? Maybe it is a 40X or other 50X error page?

Answer (score 0):

If you want get page see below:

```
  final HtmlPage enclosedPage = (HtmlPage) anchor.click().getEnclosingWindow().getEnclosedPage();
```